# Cannot shutdown AWS Sagemaker Studio after aws configure credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm trying to create a notebook job in sagemaker studio, but it complains about credentials with:

> You're not authenticated to your AWS account: you haven't provided AWS security keys or they are expired. Authenticate with valid security keys bbefore creating a notebook job.

And says to run aws configure, I do that and set my credentials, but if I do that when trying to shutdown the studio notebook instance it says that I cannot stop the app because the token is invalid

> Error Stopping Server: Error deleting app. Error message: the security token included in the request is invalid. Args: undefined.

,so I cannot shutdown the notebooks when not used.

In summary I have: if I set credentials with aws configure I cannot exit the notebook server, but if I don't I cannot create notebook jobs.

Question: how to exit notebook instance after setting credentials with aws configure?
Will setting the secret and access key in a lifecycle script solve it?(but is it a good practice, I guess is a security breach)

Comment: In this case, you are better of automating it as part of your Lifecycle config script using the AutoShutdown plugin - https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-auto-shutdown-extension